# Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to understand how migrating from discord.py version 1.7.3 to 2.0 works. In particular, this is test code I'm using:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

with open('token.txt', 'r') as f:
    TOKEN = f.read()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', help_command=None)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('bot is ready')

@bot.command()
async def test1(ctx):
    print('test command')

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

In discord.py 1.7.3, the bot prints 'bot is ready', and I can do the command `$test1`.

In discord.py 2.0, the bot prints 'bot is ready', but I can't do the command, and there isn't any error message in the console when I'm trying to do the command.

Why does this occur, and how can I restore the behaviour of version 1.7.3 in my bot?

Comment: In discord.py 2.0 you need to enable message intents for normal commands to work correctly, both in the developer portal and in your code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Use Intents with discord.py

1. Enable Intents

   - On [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
   - Select your application
   - Click on the Bot section
   - And check `MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT`

   [image: Help_Image_Intents_Message_Content]

---

2. Add your intents to the bot

   Let's add the [message_content](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content) Intent now.

   ```py
   import discord
   from discord.ext import commands

   intents = discord.Intents.default()
   intents.message_content = True

   bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents, help_command=None)
   ```

---

3. Put it together

   The code should look like this now.

   ```py
   import discord
   from discord.ext import commands

   with open('token.txt', 'r') as f: TOKEN = f.read()

   # Intents declaration
   intents = discord.Intents.default()
   intents.message_content = True

   bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents, help_command=None)

   @bot.event
   async def on_ready():
       print('bot is ready')

   # Make sure you have set the name parameter here
   @bot.command(name='test1', aliases=['t1'])
   async def test1(ctx):
       print('test command')

   bot.run(TOKEN)
   ```