# How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I'm using Heroku as my server host of my Discord.py bot, but i am having a problem. the problem is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
        client = discord.Client()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
Process exited with status 1
```

However here is my discord.py `code`

```py
import discord
token = '(Obviously the token is here)'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Which `discord.py` version are you using?

Comment: @Dominik The latest `1.7.3`

Comment: The latest would be `2.?`. I guess you are using that as the error should not happen in `1.7.3`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A little disclaimer:** Join the [discord.py](https://discord.com/invite/r3sSKJJ) server for more information, there are weekly updates since they are actively developing the library and changes can be breaking.

Now every `Client` subclass needs the `intents` keysword as mentioned in the following picture:

[image: https://discord.com/invite/r3sSKJJ]

**How to change the code:**

1. Head over to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and click on your application
2. Head over to `Bot`and find `Privileged Gateway Intents`. Tick whatever you need
3. In your code, you then need to import them:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default() # or .all() if you ticked all, that is easier
intents.members = True # If you ticked the SERVER MEMBERS INTENT

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents) # "Import" the intents
```

This should resolve your error.

Comment: The bot was successfully connected to discord with Heroku, but the new problem is, commands are not working anymore, if i do `.ping` aren't returning something, that it should've returned the latency.

Comment: @BedazzlingTRUES This is not really related to your question anymore. I assume it is something with Heroku itself or your indentation.

Comment: @BedazzlingTRUES [How to define a command in discord.py 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/how-to-define-a-command-in-discord-py-2-0)