# Client.__init__() "missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'", or "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make a quick bot for discord and I used this code:

```
import discord
from discord.ui import button, view
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Autenticazione riuscita. {0.user} è online!'.format(client))
```

But this error pops up:

```
Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

I tried providing an argument by putting something between the brackets, like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ui import button, view
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client(0)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Autenticazione riuscita. {0.user} è online!'.format(client))
```

But instead I get this error:

```
Client.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

On another PC the exact same code, with exact same modules and same Python version works just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Intents)  are now [required](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Client) in `discord.py==2.0.0` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this Error in Discord.py on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-fix-this-error-in-discord-py-on-heroku)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could use the default `Intents` unless you have a particular one to specify.

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

As the first error message says, it is a *keyword-only* argument, so you cannot write `discord.Client(discord.Intents.default())` without `intents=`.

See [Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Intents) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

With older versions, you can't get the messages.

Try using this

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion here would be to uninstall the version of discord.py you currently have and install version 1.7.3.

I was having the same issue and realized that a new version of the module had been released recently. Once I reverted back to an older version, everything worked by just using

```
client = discord.Client()
```

Answer (score -3):

i had the same issue, its a version issue use:
pip install -U discord==1.7.3
pip install -U discord.py==1.7.3

this should fix it,
at least for me it did

Comment: It's the same answer as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73641110/2745495