# newbie mistake in discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I just started writing code for discord bots and this one constantly gives an error on this line, what should I do? I'll post the error below.

```
bot = commands.Bot('bot.', description='Крутой бот).')
bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\discordmusik\venv\main.py", line 490, in <module>
bot = commands.Bot('bot.', description='Крутой бот).')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677) should fix your error, you're missing intents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in line
`bot = commands.Bot('bot.', description='Крутой бот).')` 1 mandatory argument is expected named `intents`.

That is what the error is specifying. To fix it you need to pass an intent argument while calling `commands.Bot`.

Try this :

```
import discord 

intent = discord.Intents.default()
intent.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot('bot.', intents=intent, description='Крутой бот).')
bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```