# How do i define ''intents'' when making a python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i am very new to coding. i'm using VS code, i watched a tutorial, this is my code. It says ''intents'' is not defined

code:

```
import discord 

token = "mytokencuzsecuritynstuff"

client = discord.Client(Intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"logged in as {client.user}")

client.run(token)
```

what do i do to fix this?

Comment: `Intents` is a non-existent variable so you'll get this error. Remove it so it looks like `client = discord.Client()`. If you want to specify `intents`, refer to [the Discord Client documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score -1):

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False
token = 'your token'
#add other intents according to your needs
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client.run(token)
```

The error was because you hadn't defined intents in the first place.
As you are new, I recommend you to learn discord.ext intead.