# Discord bot with python

Tags: python, encoding, discord, discord.py

so i'm coding a discord bot with python. when i type this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= "!")
```

and run this comes up:

```
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. Do your research (e.g., paste error messages into google) before posting here.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677) should fix your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add intents into parameters.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Or you can use `pip install discord.py==1.7.3` which doesn't require you to pass in intents as a parameter.

Comment: thats how i got here