# BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord.py

Im making a discord bot with python but im getting this error but dont know how to fix it :( [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTqcK.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It asks you to add the intents.
Do this :

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

EDIT :
You could also parameter the intents as to what you could access with your bot :

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
```

EDIT2 : to go deeper :
You also need to enable intents for your bot in the discord portal :
https://discord.com/developers/applications/
You'll have a "bot" section on the left. You scroll down to "Privileged Gatewatays Intents" and you have to enable the ones you'll use.
You can find all these in the docs, aswell as other possible options to Intents (like the Intents.Default() ), depending of what your bot will do.
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html