# TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord.py

So Im making a discord selfbot:

```
prefix = input("\033[0;96m[~\033[0;96m] \033[0;96mPREFIX - ")
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True,
                  self_bot=True)
client.remove_command('help')
header = {"Authorization": f'Bot {token}'}
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
#yt links doesnt work
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
```

but then this error keeps coming

```
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the intents argument in client, I did this:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all(), case_insensitive=True, self_bot=True)
```

It should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The first part of your code should be:

```
prefix = input("\033[0;96m[~\033[0;96m] \033[0;96mPREFIX - ")

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True,
                  self_bot=True)
```

This should remove your error