# What is and How to fix this error in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I was using replit (maybe because replit doesnt work?) tryoing to make some code for a Discord bot when I saw this:

`Type error: __init__ missing 1 required keyword-only argument: "intents"`

Im not really sure what is means

Heres my code (BTW i used ***pip install discord*** in shell)
`

```
import discord


token = "mytoken (not revealing it i guess)"# but even with right token it doesnt work

client = discord.Client()


name = "MIIB.BOT_v1.0"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot logged in as ", name, "!")

client.run(token)

on_ready()


#i did *****pip install discord****** in shell btw
```

`

I tried some variations but not much. I expected:
`Bot logged in as botname#6969`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
client = discord.Client()
```

with

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Answer (score 0):

As per recently(-ish), you need to specify the intents your bot uses when login to the API, so you should populate the Client argument with an intent object.

Calling the default intents, if you don't plan on doing anything with any other that you might need to enable, would look like this

```
bot_intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=bot_intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your intents with:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

You won't need any other intents than this for your code.
But if you ever run into an error you can do

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

(But you have to turn intents all on in the [Discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).)