# I have a problem with (commands) and I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, discord.py, bots

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is runing now!!!")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<')

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Seems `intents` argument is required.

You can find information here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.ext.commands.Bot.intents

intents property takes value of type discord.Intents (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents).
Although you can also pass it as `None`.

Example:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<', intents=None)
```

or

```
import discord
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='<', intents=discord.Intents())
```