# I'm trying to make a streaming status with animated status and such but ran into this problem

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=':', self_bot=True)
intents missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
exit status 1
```

This worked at first but ended up here.
This is a self bot that runs streaming status with rich preference and animated status for the streaming status.

Here is the code:

```py
with open('config.json') as f:
    config = json.load(f)
    token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
    
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=':', self_bot=True)

def Clear():
    os.system('cls')

Clear()

def Init():
    token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
    try:
        bot.run(token, bot=False, reconnect=True)
        os.system(f'title (Activity Statuses)')
```

Comment: it is a selfbot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents)

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce `intents`. Replace the line

```py
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix=':', self_bot=True)
```

with

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True # allows self-bot to access member information
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=':', self_bot=True, intents=intents)
```

Comment: thanks this did help but i runned into a new problem.

Comment: The error says sh: 1: cls: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 60, in <module>
    bot.loop.create_task(ready())
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined

Comment: the code is: def Init():
    token = os.getenv("TOKEN")
    try:
        bot.run(token, bot=False, reconnect=True)
        os.system(f'title (Activity Statuses)')
    except discord.errors.LoginFailure:
        print(f"{Fore.RED}[ERROR] {Fore.YELLOW}Improper token has been passed"
              + Fore.RESET)
        os.system('pause >NUL')