# Discord bot not sanding message

Tags: python-2.7, discord.py, bots

I'm programming a discord bot with python for the first time, my problem is that no event inside the code works, except on ready which works,

```
import discord as ds

import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("token.envella")
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
client = ds.Client(intents = ds.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():   
    print(f"{client.user} is Ready")    

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "c":
       await message.channel.send("dasdsada")

       await client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'messaggio di benvenuto per {member.name}'
    )

client.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

I tried various web solutions (client.process_commands(message)) but without getting results Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: You're missing `message` intents, you may see an example from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents).

Comment: Your bot is missing the `message_content` intent needed for the `on_message()` event to work (besides dms, own bot messages and messages with a bot ping) and `members` intent needed for the `on_member_join()` event to work. One way to fix it is to change `ds.Intents.default()` by `ds.Intents.all()` in the client initialization. By the way, are you using python-2.7? If not, please modify the tag

Comment: Also enable intents within the developer portal itself.