# Making discord bot with python but when I try to pass intents to discord.Client() it tells me that it takes one positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord

I can't figure out how to pass in the intents without getting this error.

I used this:

```
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents)
```

But got the error stated earlier.

Comment: Does this resolve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() "missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'", or "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents-or-tak)