# File"c:\_bard-bot\main.py", line 3, in <module>client=discord.Client(),TypeError:Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote a code to display the status and activity of Discord, but I got the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\_bard-bot\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```py
import discord, asyncio, dotenv, bardapi
    
client = discord.Client()
    
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, 
    activity=discord.Game("Testing"))
      
dotenv_file = dotenv.find_dotenv()
dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)
client.run("DISCORD_TOKEN")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Client.\_\_init\_\_() "missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'", or "takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents-or-tak)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the intents used by your bots, here is the documentation: [discord.Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client#discord.Intents).

You can use the default intents by using `Intents.default()`:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```