# Discord Client error when running discord bot with python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, discord, discord.py, replit

So I was first running my code on replit.com and I decided to switch over to running it localy on my computer. I got it running on Python IDLE 3.10.1 and then I decided to run it on VS Code with the same interpreter and then I got an error:

```
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

On this line of code:

```
client = discord.Client()
```

And this line of code was working both on replit and on IDLE and after running it on VS code it stopped running on IDLE aswell. And after I fixed the error with this I found on stack overflow:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

The bot seems to be running in the console, but in reality it isn't running because it isn't responding to my commands.

I also get [these weird messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DiR2.png) before the bot "starts":

TLDR; Running discord bot on replit, switched to Python IDLE 3.10.1 kept working, switched to VS Code error appeared, fixed error, bot not working anymore on IDLE and VS Code.

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing) help?

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT I tried it and it and the bot still "works", but isn't responding to commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

Code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And from the discord dev portal you need to enable whatever priviledges you want, in my case [message priviledges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UseKK.png)