# Discord.py client definition required intend argument

Tags: discord.py, bots

```
client =  commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

I'm getting this error, and the problem is that the line hasn't been changed. I have been developing the bot for a long time, that's why I'm confused. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the default `Intents`.

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.default())
```