# discord.py TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

`bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`

`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents`

```py
from discord.ext import commands
#from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
#import discord

import os


bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
```

How to fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing)

Answer (score 3):

In this case you just need to specify the `intents` keyword argument.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

## Read

---

- [How do I get the discord.py intents to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831017/how-do-i-get-the-discord-py-intents-to-work)
- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html