# İ need your help on python for discord bot

Tags: discord.py

this is my code ;

->  client = discord.Client()

and my error is ;

->   client = discord.Client()
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Does this help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71959420/client-init-missing-1-required-keyword-only-argument-intents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know without seeing all of your code, but the error there is pretty clear and gives you a starting place.

It says you are missing an argument inside the parenthesis for discord.Client(), and it expects to get "intents" in there.

The Discord documentation has this which might be helpful:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Then you should be able to do client = discord.Client(intents=intents) to get past the error.

Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html