# client = discord.Client() TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents' How do I fix this? New to python

Tags: python, discord, bots

Hey I'm new to python and I'm trying to create a multifunctional discord bot my bot is called **flea**. Anyway I encountered this error but I don't know how to fix it, I'm usually relatively quick to understand errors but I can't seem to figure this out. [This is what my code looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUJoT.png). The code is intended to make my bot go from offline to online on discord (running) by running the "on_ready" function

The following images is what my code looked like after I tried to fix the issue, the change did nothing but remove the error, the bot still won't appear online on discord: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7KNY.png), [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv1GO.png)

Below is my current code in my bot.py file, with the same error

```
> # imports import discord  # importing discord import responses  # importing responses.py file
> 
> 
> async def send_message(message, user_message, is_private):
>     try:
>         response = responses.response_handle(user_message)
>         await message.author.send(response) if is_private else await message.channel.send(response)
>     except Exception as e:
>         print(e)
> 
> 
> def run_flea():
>     token = 'my token'
>     client = discord.Client()  # here is the error
> 
>     @client.event
>     async def on_ready():  # this is when the bot gets started, it will call the "on_ready" function
>         print(f'{client.user} is now running')  # this tells us that our bot is up and ready
> 
>         client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please post the code as text not an image.

Comment: Updated it now :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing)

Answer (score 3):

This is because you need to declare the intents as the parameter for the client variable just insert this parameter and it should work:

```
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
```

Comment: I did and it removes the error, I guess that solves the problem but my bot still doesn't seem to appear online on discord. I think it has to do with @client.event cause when I call the function 'run_flea' from another file (I have imported it) it only seems to run until '@client.event'