# TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'

Tags: python, error-handling, compiler-errors, bots, chatbot

Can somebody assist me here with the error I'm getting?

The code:

```
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from neuralintents import GenericAssistant


chatbot = GenericAssistant('intents.json')
chatbot.train_model()
chatbot.save_model()

client = discord.Client()

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('TOKEN')
TOKEN = "my token"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("!"):
        response = chatbot.request(message.content[2:])
        await message.channel.send(response)

client.run("my token")
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-----\Desktop\Bot\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    client = discord.Client()
TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

I am not quite sure why I'm getting this error, it used to work like this in the past.

Have there been any changes made?

Comment: Maybe that helps you as well [client = discord.Client() TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents' How do I fix this? New to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73421068/client-discord-client-typeerror-client-init-missing-1-required-keywor)

Comment: Check this example: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html
`intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud pass the argument 'intent' to the Client constructor. You can try to replace the line:

```py
client = discord.Client()
```

with:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```