# Python bot Discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with the code does not work on one computer, and on the other works. All the libraries seem to be installed.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>>')

# RUN client.run('MYTOKEN')
```

Error:

> TypeError: BotBase.init() missing 1 required keyword-only argument:
> 'intents'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve the following error in discord.py: "TypeError \_\_init\_\_() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950432/how-to-resolve-the-following-error-in-discord-py-typeerror-init-missing)

Answer (score -1):

You need to have 'intents', try adding this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

You can change the ! to whatever prefix you want btw.

Comment: It doesn't work