# Discord.py bot commands don't respond when using Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I have a pre made Code with Discord.py and hosted using Heroku, it is currently online except that whenever i use a command, it returns nothing, but when running it locally using `Notepad++` the commands are working just fine.

main.py

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
token = 'OBVIOUSLY THE TOKEN IS HERE'
prefix = "?"
intents = discord.Intents.default() # or .all() if you ticked all, that is easier
intents.members = True # If you ticked the SERVER MEMBERS INTENT

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, intents=intents) # "Import" the intents
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Internal has connected to Discord!')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Discord"))
    
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! In {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')

@bot.command()
async def about(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(title='About me!', description=f'Im an Utility bot, that is coded under discord.py\n\n> Statistics\nLatency: `{round(bot.latency * 1000)}`ms', color=0xEE8700)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, *, content:str):
    await ctx.send(content)

bot.run(token)
```

Versions:
`python= 3.8.8`
`discord.py= 1.7.3`

Comment: It's probably a hosting problem. Does the bot even connect (runs `on_ready`)? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: Yes it does @EricJin on heroku logs, it has the "Internal has connected to Discord", here is the full logs:
```
2022-04-23T14:55:04.982219+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to
 starting
2022-04-23T14:55:11.559145+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command
 `python quantum.py`
2022-04-23T14:55:12.273666+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting t
o up
2022-04-23T14:55:15.469252+00:00 app[worker.1]: Internal has connected to Discor
d!
2022-04-23T14:55:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

Comment: Will it run in DMs? Can you, eg, send a message to a random channel? Is there some kind of quirk in heroku that prevents this from working?

Comment: @EricJin i tried on DM, it worked on DMs, though on other Channels it doesn't return anything.

Comment: That means heroku probably installed you the 2.0 version. Try doing `intents.messages = True` and seeing if it works in guilds. Or @ the bot in the command and see if that works.

Comment: @EricJin I changed my `requirements.txt` and removed the one that installs the discord.py 2.0, it worked now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a command in Discord.py 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/how-to-define-a-command-in-discord-py-2-0)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs it’s not a duplicate. The other question is asking about dpy 2.0, while this one is about why it doesn’t work - the author did not know that 2.0 was installed.

Comment: @EricJin While I agree that, from the comments, the question is not a duplicate, the question on its own is a duplicate and therefore I have flagged it as such. The question states that the problem is their discord bot not responding to commands, which is answered by the linked question. It was a toss-up between a dupe and NDD, since if debugging details were included it would change the nature of the question and would make the question more accurate. However, these were not [edit]ed into the question, so I flagged as a dupe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(Adding this as an answer because I assume someone else will have this problem)

In discord.py version 1.7.3, the messages intent, which is required for viewing message content, is set enabled by default. However, in 2.x you need to set it separately.

You can solve the issue by:

1. Force discord.py version to go back to 1.7.3 in `requirements.txt`; or
2. Explicitly enable the intents by doing [`intents.message_content = True`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents.message_content).