# discord.py not responding to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I give the bot a command, it doesn't reply.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=">")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

The on_ready function works perfectly, displaying "Bot is ready!" in the console, however, when I type ">hello" in the discord channel, it doesn't reply.

Comment: What is your discord.py version? If it is 1.7.x or 2.x, do you have message intents on? Do you have any events like `on_message` in the bot?

Comment: It is the latest discord.py version, and no, I do not have any events like on_message.

Comment: "Latest" can mean different things depending on the package manager. What is `print(discord.__version__)`? If it's 2.x then you do need to enable message intents *explicitly*.

Comment: is there any error when you type that command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a command in Discord.py 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/how-to-define-a-command-in-discord-py-2-0)

Comment: is there any error when you run the command

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Bot has enough permissions to send messages.

To do so. Go to https://discord.com/developers/applications then click your application, head to the **OAuth2** tab, then you will see several choices on **Scopes** find the **bot** and then Check it. After clicking the **Bot** you'll see a new tab on which below are all of the permissions. **Click the permission(s)** you desire, then copy the link that appears... Lastly reinvite the bot.

This should resolve the error, however if have more question, please comment them down.

Comment: I gave it admin permissions this time and selected the bot and applications.commands scopes, but the bot still won't respond to my command.