# Python bot stopped responding to messages after updating discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I updated discord.py using the command `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py`

After this, I received the error `TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`

I then replaced `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")` with `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())`

From there the code ran, but none of my commands were getting any response. Here is some of my code (code doesn't work even when I deleted all of my other commands):

```
from discord.ext import commands
from dhooks import Embed
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ui import Button, View


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())

token = "tokenhere"

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel([test server channel ID])
    await channel.send("I'm online!")
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.command(brief = "Returns 'pong' if the bot is online and provides the latency")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! That took {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms!')

client.run(token)
```

It is important to note that "I'm online" is successfully sent by the bot in my test server.

I'm not sure how to fix this error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define a command in Discord.py 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/how-to-define-a-command-in-discord-py-2-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable the [`message_content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents.message_content) intent (as well as enable the corresponding toggle on the Discord Developers page for your bot) in order to receive all messages now:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
```

See [the discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#privileged-intents) for more info.

Comment: Alright thanks! I also had to enable Message Content Intent on the Discord Developer portal.