# Python Discord Bot NOT Responding in Servers (all permissions given) but Working Perfectly Fine in DMs

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I'm using Pycord to code the Discord bot in Python. I need to add Slash Commands later, so no discord. py

The bot used to work fine before. Now it only responds to commands in DM, but not in Servers.

All the required Permissions are given. The bot is shown online.

```
import discord
import os
import json
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
import aiohttp

# Gets token from a file
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv('discord_token.env')
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="--")

bot.remove_command("help")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('The bot is logged in '+str(len(bot.guilds))+' servers!')
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("--help"))

@bot.command()
async def a(ctx):
    try:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="A", color=0xCC0066)

    except Exception as ex:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Something went wrong with A", color=0xCC0066)
        print("Error in A")
        print(ex)

    finally:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Command not found. Please try --help", color=0xCC0066)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        print("Command error has occurred")
        print(error)

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: How long ago was "before" when it used to work just fine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: @PedroFracassi 1 day gap.. I installed pycord and uninstalled discord.py to add slash commands

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs I enabled Intent according to the link, added respective code, and it's working now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when there are no intents enabled

Go to `discord.com/developers/applications`

Choose your application

Go to bot section

Scroll down and enable all intents

Add this to your code.

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="--",case_insensitive=True,intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Comment: Enabling all intents isn't good practice. It can lead to an API ban in the future when using the API too many times. Also, to enable all intents you would use ```discord.Intents.all()``` instead.

Comment: @BlueRobin`discord.intents.default()` also works 

But as you say I know intents is not good but pycord is a fork that forces a user to enable it. If not then the same error mentioned above occurs

Comment: @BlueRobin u can see the comments on the initial message and it seems it is resolved by enabling intents