# My discord bot isn't throwing any error but it's not responding to anything either

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

So, basically i was trying to make a bot for discord using python and this is my first project so i was trying out new stuffs
here's my code

```
import discord
from http import client
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='`')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is online")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return 

    if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send('Welcome to the server, human')

@client.command
async def info(ctx):
    await ctx.send(ctx.guild)

    
client.run(#mytokenishereicantshareit)
```

as you can see i am completely new to programming in general, so if you may help me out, the bot is saying "Bot is online" in output and it's getting online in my server its not showing any errors either. but it's none of my commands are working, like the "hello" and `info.

Edit : This issue has been fixed, There are two possible solutions for this either you can replace the `@client.event` with `@client.listen` or just add a `await bot.process_commands(message)` after

```
if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send('Welcome to the server, human')
```

Part like

```
if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send('Welcome to the server, human')
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

and you're done.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need to enable intents, in the Discord Developer Portal AND in the code.
You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558677/14327609) to enable Intents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: Seems like intents is the issue. (I'm not going to vote to close yet.) See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677. Also, there's no need to make a client and a bot, because the `commands.Bot` subclasses `Client` so it does everything a client does.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, remove the `client = discord.Client()` bit because the bot already does that, and secondly, add a bracket after the `@client.command` so it's `@client.command()`

Comment: First of all, thank you for replying to my question, and second is i tired both of things you asked me for but it's not working (it's still saying that the bot is online but it's not taking any commands), also we could talk in discord if you have, cuz i know i will run in these sort of problems everyday from now on. (bl'iueisgiurnded#9342 you can add me if you want to)