# Discord.py bot only displaying 1 member in all guilds

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I have my Discord bot setup to display the member count in its presence, but it is only showing the number 1 for the user count yet I have 2 members in the server that the bot can see. I have enabled presence and members intents on the application dashboard.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.presences = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents, activity=discord.Activity(
    type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"{len([discord.client.Guild.members])} users"), status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb)

bot.run("")
```

Comment: try using `discord.Intents.all()`?

Comment: Yes I gave that a shot and still it only displayed 1

Comment: Intents should be set in the Discord Developer Portal too, have a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558677/14327609)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it will always display `1` no matter how many members it has access to.

Look at this line:

```py
name=f"{len([discord.client.Guild.members])} users"
```

This sets the displayed user count to the length of `[discord.client.Guild.members]`. The length of that is 1, because you just created a new list with all the members being the first element.

---

However, `discord.client.Guild.members` isn't how to get the member count. (I don't even think those names exist.)

To properly get all the members in every guild, you need to [loop through every guild that the client is in](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.guilds) and [count each one's members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.member_count):

```py
member_count = sum([guild.member_count for guild in bot.guilds])
```