# I can used discord.py command before but now it's not work

Tags: python, discord.py

Could have used any command, but now it's not work.I have no idal to fix this.I really can used before.How many times i run my code and i checked it I don't think i made any mistakes please help me Her's my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!' , intents=intents)

with open('setting.json','r',encoding='utf8') as jfile:
    jdata = json.load(jfile)

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('>>Bot is online<<')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="SSIS-468 河北彩花の濃厚な唾液性交"))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} join!')
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(jdata['Welcome_Channel']))
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} join!')

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} leave!')
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(jdata['Welcome_Channel']))
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} leave!')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{round(bot.latency*1000)}(ms)')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

bot.run(jdata['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: Are there any errors that occurs during running the code? It seems fine.

Comment: It's can work but I can't use command

Comment: Please describe in more detail what and how it's not working the way you expect it to work (https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3). Although, this is just a guess as you haven't provided any debugging details.

Answer (score -1):

A couple of things I found:

1. From what I can see you didn't have message intents enabled.
2. `get_channel` is now `fetch_channel`.
3. I added some things in with the json for easier locating of the setting.json file.

I was able to use my token and get this code to work. You should be good to go!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import sys

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '!' , intents=intents)

with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'setting.json'),'r', encoding='utf8') as jfile:
    jdata = json.load(jfile)

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('>>Bot is online<<')
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="SSIS-468 河北彩花の濃厚な唾液性交"))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{member} join!')
    channel = bot.fetch_channel(int(jdata['Welcome_Channel']))
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} join!')

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{member} leave!')
    channel = bot.fetch_channel(int(jdata['Welcome_Channel']))
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} leave!')

@bot.command(name='ping')
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{round(bot.latency*1000)}(ms)')

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()



bot.run(jdata['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: `get_channel` is preferred over `fetch_channel` - making API calls pointlessly is pointless. Also, if you're having to give three different answers in one post, maybe this isn't the type of questions you should be answering. See the [how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) where it talks about which types of questions to answer. Questions that ask you to debug their code are useless to anyone except the asker, so you're doing yourself a disservice by taking the time to write an answer.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs - I didn't give 3 different answers, I outlined the changes I made to the code. As for answering questions, I don't have the haughty attitude you do, and if I can assist someone with an answer, I enjoy helping. I've always appreciated the people who assisted me when I needed it. So I choose to take the time to write an answer. As for `get_channel`, I haven't been able to get it to work since July 25th or so when Discord had its webhook issue. `fetch_channel` works.