# Why doesn't my discord.py bot see messages in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a basic discord bot (python) and it should print out into the terminal who messaged what and in what channel. The only issue is when it prints out the message part in the terminal it is blank as if nothing was there. My code is intended to respond but it isn't "seeing" what I message in discord. There is no error message.

[image: Image of the terminal]

```
import discord
import random
import os



client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel}))')
```

Then I would make it respond to what I messaged but it doesn't SEE the message.
If it's a really stupid mistake sorry I'm a starter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should activate the **message content intent** in discord.com/developers/applications then replace :
 `discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())`
With

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

[message content intent activation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFyvM.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had done part 1 of going in discord developers thing but was missing that last part. :)