# My discord bot won't respond to commands in a server but responds to commands in private messages?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have no clue why this is, does it have to do with discord developer portal settings?
[image: this is what logs are saying] This is what logs are saying when I say !help in the channel, the bot doesn't seem to register the content of the message?

This is my current code:

> ```
>     > import discord
>     > 
>     > token = "my token"
>     > client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
>     > 
>     > 
>     > @client.event  # when this is hit the function "on_ready" gets ran
>     > async def on_ready():
>     >     print(f'{client.user}: ONLINE')
>     > 
>     > 
>     > # bot functionality 
>     > @client.event async def on_message(message):
>     > 
>     >     # preventing endless response loop
>     >     if message.author == client.user:
>     >         return
>     > 
>     >     # !help function
>     >     if message.content == "!help":  # when I call this function for instance, it works in private messages but not in the server channel
>     >         print("Running !help")
>     >         await message.channel.send("help message")
>     > 
>     >     # logging (ignore this)
>     >     username = str(message.author)
>     >     user_message = str(message.content)
>     >     channel = str(message.channel)
>     >     print(f"{username} said: '{user_message}' ({channel})")  # logging purposes
>     > 
>     > client.run(token)  # we need the token to authorize the bot in order
>     > for it to run
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an issue with intents. You should use

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Also, please note that as of august 31st, you will need to enable the message content intent in the discord developer portal. For more info see https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ