# discord.py bot not sending messages

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as {0.user}".format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("Hello"):
        await message.channel.send("Hi")
client.run("Token")
```

this is a code i basically copied from a tutorial, and even tho it is a 1 to 1 copy of the code shown it still doesn't send messages

Comment: Which version? In v.2.0 you need the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent to receive messages.

Comment: discord==1.7.3                                                                                                          discord.py==2.0.0

Comment: @puncher can you pls send me some further explanation?

Comment: As I already said, you need the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent. Activate it in the Discord Developer Portal and set it to `True`: `intents.messages = True`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [https://discord.com/developers/applications/YOUR_BOT_ID/bot](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) and enable the message content intent

you can also try to replace `discord.Intents.default()` by `discord.Intents.all()`

Hope it helps!