# Discord.py V2 not recognizing command, mistaking for message event

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Wanted to drop an odd issue i've been having.

It seems, despite having process_commands in my message event function, it is still processing any commands as simple messages. This is odd because the file was working before. What I end up with with this code and sending >helloworld is a print out of the message object from the message event function.

Here's my code, if anybody could tell me what they know that would be huge.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    
    print(f'[*] bot connected.')
    

class Menu(discord.ui.View):
    
    def __init__(self, args, *kwargs):
        self.guild_id = kwargs.pop('guild_id')
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.value = None

    @discord.ui.button(label="Yes", custom_id="yes", style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def button_yes(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        print(True)


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
   
    
    print(message)

    do stuff here
    
    await bot.process_commands(message)
        
        
@bot.command()
async def helloworld(ctx):

    view = Menu()
    await ctx.channel.send('test', view=view())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs it does, was a combination of the privileged intents and that message content line.. had one, missing the other. Thank you!