# Token connection impossible (bot discord)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Whenever I run the code the bot goes online but does not work and there is this error message.

"discord.client: logging in using static token"
"discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 5dbf4e11d5000c1289cff197f28a97cd)."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyzmc.png)

```
import discord

default_intents = discord.Intents.default()
default_intents.members = True

client = discord.Client (intents=default_intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Le bot est prêt.")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "ping":
       await message.channel.send("pong")

client.run("token")
```

Comment: Please provide the code that produces this message and explain what is not working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've updated the post to show the code

Comment: It's not an error, it's just a logging info. What exactly doesn not work? What's in the console? Does the on_ready work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3). Note that the error you are getting is not actually an error, just standard discord.py logging.

Comment: Intents have to be enabled, specifically the `message_content`, for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error. It's a logging information of the library which got implemented in [discord.py v2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

It's comming from the gateway and from `Client.login()` which is called when you call `client.run()`:

From `Client.login()`

```
_log.info('logging in using static token')
```

From `DiscordWebSocket.received_message()` when the `READY` event is sent

```
_log.info('Shard ID %s has connected to Gateway (Session ID: %s).', self.shard_id, self.session_id)
```

It "doesn't work", because you use `on_message` without the `MESSAGE_CONTENT` intent. You need to enable it in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications) and in the code by doing this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
# ...
```

---

###### References:

- [`discord.Intents`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20intents#discord.Intents)
- More about intents: [A Primer to Gateaway Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html?highlight=intents)