# discord bot not reading commands

Tags: python, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    print("aaaa")
    await ctx.send('aaaa')
    


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

when I type in discord "$test" nothing happens, not event the print statement is called

Comment: Are you sure that the bot is connected to the Discord server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 1):

To improve privacy bots now need a special intent in order to be able to read messages. The "new" commands (which i would recommend you to switch to) are [slash commands](https://support.discord.com/hc/de/articles/1500000368501-Slash-Commands-FAQ) as they are fully supported by Discord. You can find information on how to set up slash commands [here](https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).

If you want to stick with the old method, here is he to activate the intent: First go to your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), select your application and activate the *Message Content Intent*. Next you need to activate the intent in your code like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

Note that if your bot is on 100 or more servers it needs to be verified in order to access intents. More information on that can be found [here](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055).

Comment: If you're having to add the same answer to multiple questions, it is likely that one or more of them is a duplicate. You have the reputation to [flag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) as such, you should use it :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this Discord post](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055), you have to manually enable the message content intent through the developer portal. After doing so, you can use the following code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are correct, you have to manually enable the message content intent in discord developer portal and in your code, but "intents.message_content = True" is incorrect for discord.py.

The correct code would be:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
```