# Python Discord Bot on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py, hosting

I deployed Discord on Heroku successfully, but it still doesn't work. It runs fine locally, but I can't get response from Heroku hosted variant.
Here's Github repository: https://github.com/MidnightSonor/malifaux_discord_bot.
Here's runtime log.

```
2022-10-13T12:44:01.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dashevsky.andry@gmail.com
2022-10-13T12:44:22.188723+00:00 app[api]: Release v18 created by user dashevsky.andry@gmail.com
2022-10-13T12:44:22.188723+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 56113237 by user dashevsky.andry@gmail.com
2022-10-13T12:44:24.832319+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-10-13T12:44:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-10-13T12:44:26.365888+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python3 main.py`
2022-10-13T12:44:26.952729+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-10-13T12:44:27.929643+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2022-10-13 12:44:27] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
2022-10-13T12:44:28.683273+00:00 app[worker.1]: [2022-10-13 12:44:28] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: bf35f7b917978582c1cb6a861dba38eb).
2022-10-13T12:44:30.686669+00:00 app[worker.1]: Malifaux Deck Bot#4754 has connected to Discord!
```

Comment: That's the _deploy_ log, and it shows a successful deployment. We need to see your _runtime_ logs. You can see them by running `heroku logs` or checking the logs in the dashboard.

Comment: Added. But I got both both _requirements.txt_ and _runtime.txt_ in root, what else can make app incompatible with standard python package?

Comment: Erm, nope, that's a _different_ deploy log that's showing errors. A `requirements.txt` file in the root directory should be sufficient, but see what the error says: "One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch." Are you trying to deploy from a non-`main`, non-`master` branch?

Comment: No, I have only one branch, which, ofc, is _main_. And another attempt to get log.
NOPE. I got another app in main directory, trying to fix it

Comment: Remade project and deleted old one but still no results. Added another log, is it the one which can help?

Comment: Fixed, Discord shows that bot online but it doesn't respond to commands. Is there way to check what's wrong now?

Comment: @AndryDashesky You need to enable the message_content privileged intent

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Do you mean bot options on Discord Developer portal or using method _all_ for creating _client_ type?

Comment: See this or similar questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73581119/discord-bot-not-reading-commands

Comment: @AndryDashesky The same applies if you are using Client or Bot; to read message content, you need to enable the message content intent on the portal AND set message_content to true on the intents object you pass to the Client/Bot, using discord.Intents.all() should also be fine if you have all the privileged intents enabled in the portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris and @DenverCoder1 I got the answer. But it's mostly general recommendations and notes for discord.py and heroku firsttimers:

1. Check which project you deploy! You can change it by `heroku remote`.
2. Check your bot's intents both on Discord Developer Portal and in code when you declare `client` or `bot` types! I used `discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())` for this purpose.
3. Read your runtime logs! Man, Im blind.