# Why is my Discord bot refusing to respond to commands now when it responded before?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot suddenly stopped responding to commands. I believe it's on Discord's end as any time I attempt to invite the bot, permissions only say "This will allow the developer to: Create commands in your server." I have a second bot that I haven't touched since the week it was made and it is having no problems. Am I doing something wrong in the developer portal? It's a super basic bot that sends text at the moment.

```
import discord
import os
 
from keep_alive import keep_alive
 
client = discord.Client()
 
 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
 
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
 
  message.content
 
  if "p.h" in message.content:
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')
 
keep_alive()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What is the single line ```message.content``` supposed to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) > select your app > navigate to "bot" in sidebar
2. Enable message content intent, to allow the bot read message sent from the user

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does. I didn't check it off at first because of the "100 servers" note. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that . You can mark this question as solved by clicking the ✅ on left. So other people can save time to answer other questions.