# Discord bot only responds per dm

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm trying to write a discord bot but he only responds to dms and not when I'm writing in a channel on a server:

```
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("I'm Online")

    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return
        else : print("Message from" + str(message.author) + ": " + str(message.content))
        if message.content.startswith("Hello Bot") :
            await message.channel.send("Hello")

client = MyClient(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run("my token")
```

I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super late, but I was experiencing the same issue and this is how I resolved it.

Try opening your Discord Developer Dashboard, open the bot in question, select bot, and scroll down to Message Content Intent, and check the option on. It reads:

MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT
Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages.

This instantly resolved the issue for me.