# The bot events doesn't working discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a simple on_message event for the bot but somehow the bot is ready and online, but no event is working...

Here is an example of my code:

```py
import discord

token = "--My token--"

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Connected to APPLICATION {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("$test"):
        await message.channel.send("test")
            
client.run(token)
```

Comment: This is happening because you haven't enabled and specified the correct intents for your bot. [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to have intents enabled in discord.py v.2.0 for it to work.
You can use `discord.Intents.all()` to enable all intents or you can also use `discord.Intents.default()` if u prefer to only enable default intents.

```
import discord

token = "--My token--"

intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Connected to APPLICATION {client.user}")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("$test"):
        await message.channel.send("test")
            
client.run(token)
```