# Discord on_message method won't read discord command prefix

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have been trying to make a Discord bot respond to on_message method and it is not replying for the 'haki.' prefix I added in Discord.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import discord

token = "mydiscordbottoken"
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
command_prefix = "haki."

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} BOT is ready'.format(client))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author != client.user and message.content.startswith(command_prefix):
        await message.channel.send(message)

client.run(token)
```

Following a tutorial. He only uses client = discord.Client(), which when I tried would give me an TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'. But when I use client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()) then run it. My discord bot is online and ready on the server. I believe that the bot can't read my discord messages based of that, but I'm not entirely sure. Any fixes would be greatly appreciated. (ex: haki.Hello should prompt the bot to say Hello)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling message content in your bot Intents as well as enabling all discord Intents:

```
import discord

token = "mydiscordbottoken"
intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
command_prefix = "haki."

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('{0.user} BOT is ready'.format(client))
    
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx,message):
    if message.author != client.user and message.content.startswith(command_prefix):
        await ctx.channel.send(message)

client.run(token)
```

Your on_message command should also have a context (ctx) variable like the one I added.

I also noticed you are commenting the bot replies you with the entire message context. Try using either of the following:

```
await ctx.reply(ctx.message.content)
await ctx.send(ctx.message.content)
await ctx.reply('Hello')
await ctx.send('Hello')
```

Answer (score -1):

The first reason I don't like is that your conditions are not separated by parentheses.

```
if (message.author != client.user) and message.content.startswith(command_prefix) == True:
```

Also, another reason is that on the developer's site, i.e. your page with bots, you need to put two sliders on the status active in permissions, then you will give permission to read messages.

[HOW ADD GATEWAY INTENTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZJy5.png)

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I gave my bot the administrator permission and it wasn't working.

Comment: Give your bot "gateway intents"
P.S check up new screenshot

Comment: Made progress, bot now responds but does not reply the way I intended it to be.

Comment: When I type haki.Hello it should respond with Hello in discord, but instead, it replies with. <Message id=1021145262502199300 channel=<TextChannel id=1021047788865327127 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=1021047788865327125> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=244622130904301569 name='PublicBathtub' discriminator='6776' bot=False nick=None guild=<Guild id=1021047788865327124 name="PublicBathtub's BOTS" shard_id=0 chunked=False member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>

Comment: Use better standard command methods, by type: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score -1):

Bots need a special intent to read your messages now.

First go to your [Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), select your application and activate the Message Content Intent. Next you need to activate the intent in your code:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

After fixing this intent problem, your bot will work but won't send the information I assume you want it to send. It will send the message **object** instead of the message content (if that's what you want), so you should use the following inside your on_message method:

```
await message.channel.send(message.content)
```