# Discord.py bot wont reply to commands

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is my first time using the Discord.py library. I have the following code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix='$')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f'Logged in as {client.user}!')

@bot.command()
async def say(ctx, arg):
  await ctx.send(arg)

client.run('MY_TOKEN')
```

When I say "$say "hello world"" I don't get any error message, but I also don't get any response from the bot. Can someone tell me what the issue is, I'm sure it's a simple mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I did wrong. I didn't need to include `client` and `bot` as separate things. I simply removed `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` and the code ran fine (obviously I replaced every instance of 'client' with 'bot').