# unknown discord.py glitch

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello I was following a discord bot tutorial video step by step yet when i publish my code and try to respond to it, it would completly ignore me and I have no idea why it does this here is the whole code.

```
import discord
import random

TOKEN = 'is here'

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')


    if message.author == client.user:
       return

    if message.channel.name == 'bot':
        if user_message.lower() == 'hello':
            await message.channel.send(f'hello {username}!')
        elif user_message.lower() == 'bye':
            await message.channel.send(f'see you later {username}!')
            return
        elif user_message.lower() == '!random':
            response = f'this is your random number: {random.randrange(50000)}'
            await message.channel.send(response)
            return

    if user_message.lower() == '!anywhere':
        await message.channel.send('this can be used anywhere!')
        return

        client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677) may fix your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you. Your client.run(token) was inside the last if statement so your bot would not have even started also you need to enable intents in your developer account otherwise the bot might not be able to read messages.
username = str(message.author).split('#')[0] is unnecessary when you can just use username = message.author.name

```
import discord 
import random
import asyncio

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
intents.guild_messages = True
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Bot(intents=intents, messages = True, guild_messages = True, message_content = True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = message.author.name
    channel = str(message.channel.name)

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.channel.name == 'bot':
        if message.content.startswith('hello'):
            await message.channel.send(f'hello {username}!')

    if message.content.startswith('!anywhere'):
        await message.channel.send('this can be used anywhere!')
        return

client.run('token_here')
```