# Discord bot does print messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm a newcomer in the discord bot scene.
I've recently started coding a bot and watched a simple tutorial for a bot that replies to simple messages like hello and bye. While testing the bot I encountered an issue not addressed in the video.

```
print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')
```

This command was meant to log the message sent by the user, but instead of this

```
MooseGaming: hello (test)
```

It just shows this

```
MooseGaming:  (test)
```

I don't know how to fix it but at one point it worked when pinging it, but then it stopped the next time I turned the program on.
If anyone would help I would be **very** thankful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a standard `f-string` so will work like this:

```py
username = 'foo'
user_message = 'bar'
channel = 'fin'


print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')
```

resulting in this:

```
foo: bar (fin)
```

So, if you are missing `bar` from the print string then the variable `user_message` was empty !!

Also, we can see the two spaces before the `(test)` word, so we can infer that `user_message` is and empty string `''`.

Comment: While this is true for python generally, and in this case user_message is `''`, this is likely because OP did not configure intents for discord.py

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, agreed,  but there was no reference to this and only the f-string in the actual question. There was no example code for the ping mentioned, so not possible to comment there.

Comment: Maybe this will help, I understand that the ```user_message``` is empty but as I show in this image that variable should not be empty. https://imgur.com/a/NRRo8tD

Comment: @MooseGaming, which part of that image showw that the `user_message` should **not** be empty ?   what do you think the value should be ?   the arrow in the image shows to me that it is actually empty !!

Comment: The discord screenshot of my message and then the console output, the ```user_message``` should be ```hello```  - what I sent on discord.

Comment: oh, okay.  maybe open a new question with the whole (minimal reproducable) code like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example   ...it would be helpful for users to understand and answer appropriately.