# Discord bot does not respond to my commands

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm a beginner to python and I am following a YouTube tutorial, and the problem is that the bot would not respond to any of the messages. Also I'm trying this on Replit. I would really appreciate your help.

```
import discord 
import os


client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.default())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
    await message.channel.send('hello')

client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Answer (score 0):

You’re only using the default intents: you haven’t set the message content intents. See these for more info:

https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-FAQ

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html