# Hey, I just created a discord bot using PyCharm and its all going good, but when i try to send !hi or hi it doesnt send Hello back. can anyone help me

Tags: discord.py, discord.net

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
import random
import time
import asyncio

TOKEN = "<My token>"

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client)) 


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith("hi"):   #whenever i type this
        await message.channel.send("Hello") #i dont get this 


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Running!")


client.run(TOKEN) #Token
```

thanks for the help,i just need the program to say hello when i say hi,
I am kinda new to making bots soo yeah. I copied this from a youtube vid, but the intents i did by myself. I am using 3.8 version of Python, it runs without errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commands don't run in discord.py 2.0 - no errors, but run in discord.py 1.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3)

Comment: I used the same code for python also, it doesnt work. but thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may be because you did not update your intents or in general something wrong with the intents,

Intents on the discord developer portal are in the `Bot` Section,
[image: Intents]

If these are enabled then try printing `message.content` to see if it returns blank or what the user says.

Comment: I enabled all the intents, it still doesnt work

Comment: Did you try printing `message.content`?
If so what did it return with?

Comment: Yep i even tried printing it, but i didnt get anything, just blank

Comment: This means your intents are set up wrong or not being registered.
Try changing `intents = discord.Intents(messages=True)`
To `intents = discord.Intents.default() *New Line*
intents.messages = True`

Comment: Really sorry man, but its still not working. Does it work for you?

Comment: I did see this from a youtube video, and i am using python 3.8, so maybe is it because of that??

Comment: Ah im glad its fixed, if I can ask what fixed it in the end?