# Accidentally kicked the chatbot out, and everything stops working right know

Tags: python, discord.py, dotenv

As said in the title, I accidentally kicked my chatbot out and after adding it back, everything is broken.

I deleted most of my codes and left some simple things.

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        if guild.name == GUILD:
            break

    print(
        f'{client.user} is connected to the following guild:\n'
        f'{guild.name}(id: {guild.id})'
    )

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to my Discord server!'
    )

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # !bot
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if '!test' in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send("You fixed it")
        
client.run(TOKEN)
```

However, only `on_ready()` prints the message out, the welcome message and the `!test` are not working at all. I created a new bot and added it to the server, only changed the bot token, still not working.

What caused this? What should I do?

Comment: Any error ? Otherwise try to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677).

Answer (score 0):

Its because you don't have intents enabled, assuming you are using `discord.py 2.0`. Starting from `discord.py 2.0` you are required to pass intents in `Client()`. You can enable the default intents with `client = discord.Client(intent=discord.Intents.default())`, if you choose to enable all intents use `all()` instead of `default()`. You can find a list of all intents [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Intents).