# Discord bot not reacting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I was trying to test my discord bot written in Python, but on sended messages, it won't react, but on message edit it send empty message.

```
import discord
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default()) 
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Jestem gotowy!')


@client.event                                                      #system reakcji na wiadomości
async def on_message(wiadomosc):
    if wiadomosc.content == "Siema Pyton":
        await wiadomosc.channel.send('Elo, co tam?')
    elif wiadomosc.content == 'co tam u ciebie pyton?':
        await wiadomosc.channel.send('a wszystko git :D')
    if wiadomosc.content == 'fajnie':
        await wiadomosc.add_reaction('\U0001F60E')
    if wiadomosc.content == 'dzień dobry':
        await wiadomosc.channel.send('A witam witam :)')
    if wiadomosc.content == '60':
        await wiadomosc.channel.send('Spadaj')
    if wiadomosc.content == 'konfident':
        await wiadomosc.channel.send('Spadaj na drzewo!')
        
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before,after):
    await before.channel.send(
        f'{before.author} zedytował wiadomość.\n'
        f'Przed: {before.content}\n'
        f'Po: {after.content}\n'
    )

client.run('tokenhere')
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558677/14327609) should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul said from the comment,
You need to do

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Then you go to the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) of the app (where u get ur token)
from the menu select BOT
[image]

Enable the messeage intent
[image]

Now your code should work fine. :D