# inside on_message in discord.py, if statements to check content doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return
    if message.content == 'hi':
      await message.channel.send("hi")
```

Why doesn't this work? The code runs without errors but it doesn't detect the message "hi"

I wanted the bot to send a message when I send a certain message.

Comment: Did you enable message intents? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677

Comment: I did but now I get an error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have 'message content intent' enabled in your Discord Developer Portal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jD6zh.png) and your program:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```