# My discord.py bot is not responding to commands or events

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Embed

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

#Prints bot is online to console
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("PythonBot is online")

#Replies Hey! if a user says Hello
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'Hello'.lower():
        await message.channel.send("Hey!")

#Ping Command
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")

bot.run("TOKEN_HERE")
```

I have made this simple program with discord.py that has an Event, the bot says Hey! when a user says Hello and a Command, that has the bot reply Pong! when a user uses the !ping command. My issue is that the bot does not respond when either of these actions happen and there are no errors raised in the terminal. I get confirmation from the API that my bot has connected to my application's token and I receive "PythonBot is online" in the terminal when I run my program but nothing else in my program seems to work.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71558677/14327609) should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [discord.py FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working):
You need to change your following 2 lines

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
```

to

```py
@bot.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
```

and that should fix your issue