# Discord bot bug not responding

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Hello im new to stackoverflow i am developping a discord bot
but it does not react to commands in my dicsord server only in mp

here is my code

`

```
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = "X"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user} succesfully logged in!')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Make sure the Bot doesn't respond to it's own messages
    if message.author == bot.user: 
        return
    
    if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author}')
    if message.content == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'Goodbye {message.author}')

    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)

def to_upper(argument):
    return argument.upper()
    
@bot.command()
async def up(ctx, *, content: to_upper):
    await ctx.send(content)
    
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

`
please help me
[IN a server :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdNHI.png)
[in a mp:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDnDh.png)

I tried a lot of thing
but nothing works i am making a nice bot for my friends and i am a noob for discord.py

Comment: [Does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so, multiple `@bot.event` can be an issue, especially if you're looking for messages.

You need to set a listener.
I also see you do not have intents set up, so you also need to do that.

when looking for messages, you'll want something like this:

```
@bot.listen()#this makes the bot only listen for the messages
async def on_message(message):
    # Make sure the Bot doesn't respond to it's own messages
    if message.author == bot.user: 
        return
    
    if message.content == 'hello':
        await message.channel.send(f'Hi {message.author}')
    if message.content == 'bye':
        await message.channel.send(f'Goodbye {message.author}')
```

And just as an additional tip: use `ctx.channel.send("message")` instead of `ctx.send("message")`.