# Discord.py bot not running

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am working on a bot and for some reason its giving me the error code of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

I have no idea why it isn't working I tried re-doing my code from the discord command docs. My current code is

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from replit import db
TOKEN = os.environ['TOKEN']

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

client = discord.Client()

@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Welcome " + ctx.message.author.mention)
    await ctx.send("Do ?commands to see all the commands")
    db["money-" + ctx.message.author.id] = "0"
    db["xp-" + ctx.message.author.id] = "0"
    db["started-" + ctx.message.author.id] = "1"

@bot.command()
async def commands(ctx):
    started = db["started-" + ctx.message.author.id]
    if started == 1:
      await ctx.send("--------------------")
      await ctx.send("Command list")
      await ctx.send("--------------------")
      await ctx.send("?commands")
      await ctx.send("Opens this menu")
      await ctx.send("--------------------")
    else:
      await ctx.send("You havent ran ?start yet!")
      
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Again I don't know much about error codes.

Comment: Have you tried passing the intents you require to the bot constructor? Exactly what the error says you should do

Comment: It worked fine before.

Comment: I dont even know what that means lol

Comment: @StrawberryAnimations you should read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71553296/commands-dont-run-in-discord-py-2-0-no-errors-but-run-in-discord-py-1-7-3/71558677#71558677), it may fix your issue

Comment: It worked fine before because you were using an old Discord.py version. You just installed a major version upgrade, so you should expect breaking changes. The migration guide explains them: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#intents-are-now-required If you don't understand that error you may want to learn some more Python before attempting an advanced project like this, discord.py isn't beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell which intents you want to use.
If you want to use every intent for example you have to write

```
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

on line 7.

You can enable your intents on https://discord.com/developers/application choose your application and then choose Bot. If you want to use all Intents, you have to enable everything under Private Gateway Intents in order to work properly.